# Make the path as variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am newbie in PowerShell and I am searching for a way to make the script more dynamic
As an example in the script file I have this line

```
cd C:\Users\Future\Desktop
```

How can I make the path dynamic ...? I mean to let the other people who will take this script file to run it without changing the username in this line?

Comment: Use [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6) or [Environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-6) `$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either add a parameter to the script or use the `USERPROFILE` variable:

```
cd (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'Desktop')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like charm. Best Regards

Comment: By the way, I have this line `convert Image.png -resize 300x300 -density 300 -quality 100 ImageNew.png`, how can I make `Image.png` as variable that takes its value from cell in excel .. as I will execute this from excel VBA

Comment: Sorry, im not into excel VBA. You probably have to add `param($image)` at the top of the script and pass the value when you invoke it (ofc, you also have to use $image instead of Image.png). You may start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon @Martin Brandl's answer, I would suggest going the Parameter route. You can set a default value for your own use while also allowing people to specify a different path when they run the script. As a small example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]$Path = "C:\Users\Future\Desktop"
)

Set-Location $Path
```

If you use the Mandatory parameter setting it will require someone to input a Path each time the script is run which is similar to using `Read-Host`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Path
)

Set-Location $Path
```

There are other parameter settings you can use for validation purposes.

I would recommend looking through this page for more information on to set up functions as it describes a lot of the options you can use in parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6